# Will html5 and Javascript replace native applications?

Tags: javascript, html

I recently attended a conference on future of the web and web development and it was a lot of focus on HTML5 and how it will impact the way we look at the web and how we will use it. The majority of the speakers meant that it will replace native application on your desktop as well as in your mobile phone.

I agree that you will be able to make a lot of great stuff with the new technology take bespin for example and the `<video>` and `<canvas>` tag will be amazing, but will it completely remove the need for native applications? Is there something you cannot do with Javascript and HTML5?

Comment: Couldn't be much more subjective. Please edit your question and tick the "community wiki" checkbox.

Comment: Remember when XML was going to solve all your problems?

Comment: wow, video playing on a canvas, what more do you need?!?

Comment: No. Edit: At the very least, web clients will be needed for web applications. After that, while web clients can be optimized for client-side applications, ultimately specialized applications for professional tasks still dominate *for a reason*: they excel at their purpose. The most capable video and audio and graphics editors will likely never be web-based. The rest is up in the air. Caveat: most applications will eventually be web-enabled for social reasons. That doesn't mean they'll be HTML/CSS/JS based.

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 and Javascript will not replace native applications. You can do many amazing things with those technologies, and there are many applications that can be done with them, but there will be always be a need for native applications as they have access to certain hardware and OS features that HTML5 and Javascript do not.

Comment: It is changing. Right now, we can just access the GPS, but in the future, we'll also access the contact list, camera, etc.

Comment: +1. HTML apps are confined to the browser UI, which means they'll always be “inside another app”

Comment: Yes it is changing, but javascript apps will always be one step back. That is when a new api pops up, you will directly have access to it in native apps, whereas you must wait for some framework/browser to support it so that you can use it. Now Microsoft solved this with WinRT. Your components written to WinRT in C#/VB.NET, can be used by javascript, but then your app will be bound to WinRT, and you can kiss goodbye for platform independence. The other alternative is that when a new api is created js api be created with it, but you can't assume all ISV will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the areas that it can. Obviously the OS won't be replaced, but between Gmail, Google docs, Meebo etc for many users the web has already replaced many desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

Iam not sure, but i think in the future most applications will be served from the web. But i think not like today.

The future will be an mix between Webclient / Desktop application. Something like Adobe Air or Applications created with Titanium.

The Desktop of the future:

- OS (what ever.. not important)
- 5 GB Harddisk
- 1 GB Ram
- very fast internet connection

No more Backups needed, access to my data at every workstation. Nearly nothing stored offline.

Comment: No keyboard or mouse because control straight from the brain. Hang on, what about just a wifi brain implant?

Comment: thats already possible, but an wifi brain implant would be fantastic. Code what you think ;)

Comment: No keyboard or mouse because touch screen will be sufficient for most uses.

Comment: No keyboard or mouse because we'll be using video-cam gesture control: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6YTQJVzwlI

Comment: Ken Olsen, founder of Digital Equipment Corp. said in 1977, "There is no reason for anyone to have a computer in his home."  Eeerie.

Comment: I do not know what that guy meant by 'computer' but in the future we will interact with thousands of computers. From nano-robots to e-paper to smart-<put your device here>

Answer (score 1):

http://pixlr.com/editor/ (a web-based photoshop alternative built in flash) shows us that there aren't a lot of desktop apps that -can't- be mirrored on the web.  Unfortunately, it's a flash10 app, not a html5 app.  So we stil have to wait for the web stack experience to catch up with the flash experience.

Answer (score 0):

What they really mean is, can't HTML5 + Javascript create any desired **UI**. You wouldn't gain anything by writing a C++ compiler in Javascript.

So what UI is hard-to-impossible in a browser? Off the top of my head:

Video editors.
Photoshop.
Music Notation.
Music Sequencers.

For completeness, what can't be hosted on a webserver? Again, applications that require large amounts of near-zero-latency data, such as recording audio and video.

Comment: Music notation is not a problem in HTML5!  See this demo: http://0xfe.muthanna.com/jsnotation/demo.html

Comment: @MadKeithV: Music notation is not that hard to *display*: there are already plugins for that. But it's very hard to create a WYSIWYG editor in any language, let along Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is another tool, and that's great, because having good tools is great.

However, getting new, more powerful tools does not negate the need for older tools.  When I got my first power drill I didn't throw away all my screwdrivers.

In a world of infinite possibilities, it's difficult to make any tool that was useful once obsolete.  There will always be a place for desktop applications even with new tools to create web applications.

Comment: Question is, how often did you use one of these after you got your first power drill? http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/4340110/2/istockphoto_4340110-old-drill.jpg

Comment: Lol - good point.  Not sure I'd equate desktop applications to THAT, but I appreciate the chuckle.